# How do I gracefully shutdown a StructureStreaming use PySpark?

Tags: pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

as topic, how do I gracefully shutdown a StructureStreaming use PySpark? when I call `spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination(timeout=100)` it always return error:**ERROR MicroBatchExecution: Query [id = 97f61bda-ae06-4bcb-9a84-a10ea0f2f349, runId = 1370184a-8fd8-4445-b4a9-d87a1b0de07c] terminated with error
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext.**

Pls give any advise for my question

Gracefully shutdown Pyspark StructuredStreaming Program

```py
spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("streaming_program") \
       .config("spark.master","spark://cluster01:7077") \
        .config("spark.deploy.mode","cluster") \
        .config('spark.executor.cores',1) \
        .config('spark.executor.memory','15G')\
        .config('spark.cores.max',1)\
        .getOrCreate()
rate_source = spark.readStream.format("rate").option("rowsPerSecond","100000").load()
rate_source = rate_source.select(
        f.to_date("timestamp").alias("rec_date"),
        "value"
    )
rate_gp = rate_source.groupby("rec_date").agg(
        f.collect_list("value")
    )
rate_gp.writeStream.format("console").outputMode("update").start()
spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination(timeout=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

This query `spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination(timeout=100)` is used to wait for the termination of a Spark Structured Streaming query or for a specified timeout (100 milliseconds in this case), whichever occurs first.

But to gracefully shutdown the session, you can use the `stop()` method to stop the underlying SparkContext and releases all resources used by it.

```
spark.stop()
```

Also, try to stop the streaming query first

```
query.stop()
```

Hope that help!

Comment: thx for comment, but spark.stop() is not working, it still post same error.

Comment: @BaronChen have you tried to stop the streaming query before stopping the spark session?
query.stop()

spark.stop()

Comment: Hi agamil, thx for reply, seems it already show less ERROR and WARN report.
```python
ERROR WriteToDataSourceV2Exec: Data source writer org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.MicroBatchWriter@4f9a170e is aborting.
23/11/08 10:04:48 ERROR WriteToDataSourceV2Exec: Data source writer org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.MicroBatchWriter@4f9a170e aborted.
```
I will find a better way to solve this problem, thx again